# Remove tracked files that would overwrite local files

Tags: git, github

I'm currently working on a group project using git as our version control. One of my team members accidentally uploaded some files that shouldn't be tracked (IDE files and the out folder). When I try to pull the latest copy, it gives me the following message:

```
Please move or remove them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

with a list of the files that would be overwritten above. My question is- is there a way to remove these files from being tracked entirely without overwriting my own IDE files? They made some changes in the commit that I would like to keep, so it wouldn't be a good idea to revert the changes and then commit again.

In summary, what I'd like to do is: keep any changes to currently tracked files, while removing two other directories.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete these files - do this in separate folder:

- Clone the repository, delete problematic files, commit and push
- Go back to your development folder and try to pull

It should work

Answer (score 0):

`git rebase --interactive` provide you a convenience to edit your commit history,
you can find the commit of your team member and amend it.

To prevent this mistake occurred once more, you'd better add a .gitignore file to ignore those unnecessary files.